# How to match regex if prefix is the same as suffix

Tags: regex

I have string `asdf-zxcv-qwer-`

and I want to replace all occurence of words between `-`
I'm using `/-[a-z]+-/` It match only `zxcv`, because hyphen before `qwer` is used as prefix after `zxcv`. How to make it match both `zxcv` and `qwer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [assertion](http://php.net/regexp.reference.assertions), either look-behind (`(?<=…)`) or look-ahead assertion (`(?=…)`), which is checked but not consumed:

```
/(?<=-)[a-z]+-/
/-[a-z]+(?=-)/
```